How to position a div (caption) relative to an image centered inside a container div?
I have a div container centered both horizontally and vertically and an image inside it which is also centered horizontally and vertically to use the container space as much as possible. Image can be both landscape and portrait.
In order to center the image inside the container I style the image with position: absolute.
I want to add a caption to the image the way it is relative to the image bottom.


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  /* the 5 props below center */
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  bottom: 2%;
  left: 2%;
  right: 2%;

  border: 1px solid black;
}

#image {
  /* https://stackoverflow.com/a/18869078/7425756 */
/*
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
*/
  max-width: 95%;
  max-height: 90%;
  border: 2px solid red;

  /* https://stackoverflow.com/a/28424339/7425756 */
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

#caption {
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
<div id="container">
  <img id="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/79/Portrait_of_Yi_Haeung_%28National_Museum_of_Korea%29.jpg/403px-Portrait_of_Yi_Haeung_%28National_Museum_of_Korea%29.jpg">
  <div id="caption">My caption</div>
</div>



I have looked at a similar questions
Absolute position relative to an image
but it is different in that it does not position the image absolutely nor does it center it horizontally and vertically.
Perhaps the problem is in the image centering I use though.
I have tried various image centering and found that position: absolute based ones lead to the caption is hard to tie to the image. While transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%); based ones lead to unpredictable position of the caption with various viewports.
Centering I took from How to vertically align an image inside a div.
I have tried flex with column direction but it puts the image not exactly into the center and still leaves the caption lagging somewhere at the bottom when trying various viewports.

use (and center) the <figure> element, and put the image and caption inside that.

Are you looking for something like this?


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

figure {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: fit-content;
}

figcaption {
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
<div id="container">
<figure>
<img  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/79/Portrait_of_Yi_Haeung_%28National_Museum_of_Korea%29.jpg/403px-Portrait_of_Yi_Haeung_%28National_Museum_of_Korea%29.jpg">
<figcaption>My caption</figcaption>
</figure>
</div>



Based on the discussion below, here are some modifications to keep the image always fully visible:


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

figure {
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 0;
  max-height: 90vh;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

figcaption {
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  color: white;
}
<div id="container">
<figure>
<img  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/79/Portrait_of_Yi_Haeung_%28National_Museum_of_Korea%29.jpg/403px-Portrait_of_Yi_Haeung_%28National_Museum_of_Korea%29.jpg">
<figcaption>My caption</figcaption>
</figure>
</div>




Thank you!
Does height: fit-content; solves placing landscape orientation pictures most effectively as well?

So what's your aim here? Do you want to make sure the image can never be larger than the viewport? (That is, never cut off top/bottom and/or left/right?)

Exactly. Just as it is described in my question (maybe in some confusing way).
Hence I used some centering stuff and width/height, max-width/max-height in my own attempts to use the space most optimally.

Okay, I tried a few modifications and added a second example above. The only issue I had was with the caption. In the end, I placed it over the bottom of the image. Sorry if that's not what you want, but hopefully it gets you closer to something useful.
